# Which has a better application for compiler design?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

It's always a daunting task to create a compiler, as most of us know. I do wonder which library has a better application for doing such, Java or C. The problem I see here is Java is substantially longer in comparison to C but has more freedom for control. C is shorter and possibly faster in compilation, but it doesn't allow for **AS** much control. In opinion, which one would have a better application for it?

Comment: 'Which library has a better application for doing such', i.e. writing a compiler, is meaningless. Are you asking which *language* is *easier* to write a compiler for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a compiler mostly requires algorithms and data structures that are not native to the standard libraries provided by either language:

- lexemes
- lexical extraction by composing many regular expressions into a multi-exit state machine
- streams of lexemes
- Abstract Syntax Trees
- Parsers for checking syntax and building ASTs
- Control flow graphs
- Control flow construction
- ... many more...

Pretty much to build a compiler you end up defining all of these  datatypes as structs or objects, and hand-writing code to implement the ideas.

So, neither C or Java is "easier" to use for this task.

With some care, the C version may be faster than the equivalent Java version.

If you really want to write a compiler quickly, you need to find a tool or framework that provides you with these structures and algorithms [such as our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=StackOverflow), so that you don't have to invent them all.